# FFXV High Resolution Texture Pack relevant for 1080p?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Yesterday I bought the Steam version of Final Fantasy XV. Today I saw that there is a high resolution texture pack for download. It says it enables me to play in high resolutions.

Are these textures only used when I play the game in 4K or will there also be better textures when I play in 1080p? (I don't own a 4K monitor) If so, would it be correct that there would be a bigger performance impact on the game with this texture pack? I have a 1070TI and an i5-6500. Currently, the games runs smooth on full detail on 1080p, with some minor stutters from time to time. Are the minimal hardware requirements shown on the steam page only for playing in 4K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texture resolution doesn’t relate to display resolution. It means that you have to zoom in more on the texture before it looks fuzzy because there is more detail in the texture.

You can likely enable the better textures without needing to play at a high display resolution. Higher resolution textures will have a performance impact no matter what display resolution you are playing at.

You do not need to have a 4K monitor to benefit from higher resolution textures. I would recommend trying the better textures and, if you see any performance problems, balancing the in game graphics settings.

Comment: I installed it, but I don't think they are worth the file size and download time. here is a comparison video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-syVEX7QUSk
I had no reaaly big performance impacts, but memory load and loading times significantly increased.

Answer (score -3):

It was proved high resolution texture doesn't bring significant quality to be worth on resolution lower than 4k.  So don't even bother downloading them

Comment: Care to source your statement?

Comment: Here is a comparison: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-syVEX7QUSk